# Parsing StringBuilder HTML to WebBrowser control using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, stringbuilder

I have the following code:

```
private StringBuilder htmlMessageBody(DataGridView dataGridView2)
{
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    //create html & table
    strB.AppendLine("<html><body><center><" +
                    "table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    //cteate table header
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" +
                        dataGridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>");
    }
    //create table body
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
        foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells)
        {
            strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" +
                            dgvc.Value.ToString() + "</td>");
        }
        strB.AppendLine("</tr>");

    }
    //table footer & end of html file
    strB.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
    return strB;


}
```

How do i call it so that it shows up in a web browser control via a click event on a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlMessageBody(yourdataGridView).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `DocumentText` property to the created HTML.  Note that you are returning a `StringBuilder` from `htmlMessageBody` so you will need to call `ToString` to get the text

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = htmlMessageBody(theDataGridView).ToString();
```