# the name htmlMessageBody does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to send a message with datagridview contents. i got the following error

> the name "htmlMessageBody" does not exist in the current context

```
// Create a message with datagridview contents in its body and set up the recipients.
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage myMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
//Try
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("almusbaahtrade@gmail.com");
//place here from address
myMessage.To.Add("Example@gmail.com");
//place here to address
myMessage.CC.Add("example@gmail.com");
//place here copy address
myMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
//call method, creating HTML from datagridview
myMessage.Body = htmlMessageBody(DataGridView1).ToString();
//place here your subject
myMessage.Subject = "Subject";

//place here SMTP server

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Example@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(myMessage);
MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
```

Comment: so, what makes you believe that the name htmlMessageBody ***should*** exist in the current context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `htmlMessageBody`:

```
private string htmlMessageBody(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

Check these SO questions for some example implementations: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077783/parsing-stringbuilder-html-to-webbrowser-control-using-c-sharp) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462559/transferring-datagrid-view-value-to-an-outlook-html-body).